# differences between contains and containstable?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, contains, containstable

I have the following queries that should be technically equivalent:

First

```
select Product_ID from ProductSearchIndexData psid
where Product_ID = 946 and contains(psid.[Text], '("exp*")')
```

Second

```
SELECT [key] as Product_ID, rank
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(ProductSearchIndexData, [Text], '("exp*")')
where [key]= 946
```

The first one returns the right result while the other returns none.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure Product_ID is the primary key of the table? (Maybe a stupid question, but I have no other ideas)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with "Keith".

The [key] field returns the full-text key values of the rows that match the criteria.
In your case it is not the productProduct_id that is key in the search table.

try

```
SELECT [key], Product_ID, rank
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(ProductSearchIndexData, [Text], '("exp*")')
where Product_ID = 946
```

Comment: well everything is exactly the same...it looks like a bug to me. I changed everything to the way it works for me with the extra overhead of using dynamic sql. Anyways thank you very much for your input...